# how to update quantity in Odoo-erp using odoo-xmlrpc library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, odoo

im trying to create a javascript function using nodejs which uses odoo-xmlrpc library to perform paiment in odoo online database.In order to do that i have to decrease the quantity of the product somehow or create a stock move.

i found this code but nothing works correctly:

```js
var Odoo = require('odoo-xmlrpc');
var odoo = new Odoo({
    url:'https://mydomain.odoo.com',
    db:'mydb',
    username: 'mydatabase',
    password: 'password'});
    
    
odoo.connect(function (err) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log('Connected to Odoo server.');
     var params = [[{
   
    'product_id': 2,
    'product_uom_id':2,
    'location_id':9,
    'picking_type_id':2,
    'location_dest_id': 13,
   
      }]];
odoo.execute_kw('stock.move','create', params, function(err, value) {
    if (err) { return console.log(err); }
    console.log(value);});
});
```

maybe can someone help me :)